# Fat bikes and pannier racks

Tags: mountain-bike

I'm trying to research fat bikes for rack attachment holes and have not seen any so far. I'm a long term commuter and must have a way of attaching my panniers to my bike. Backpacks are out because I'm a pack rat, plus I do my shopping with my bicycle and that won't work. I believe I saw one commuter with a rack that connected to his bike by attaching just above the wheel openings, but couldn't find a name on it to do some research. Can anyone offer some help? Thanks.

Comment: Cannot find a fat with attachments   Expedition fat bikes are littered with attachments.

Comment: Can't point at any, but used to be, at least, that some racks were designed to fit on the rear axle, and axle adapters for standard racks were available.

Comment: You can get a seat post rack. The only problem is that they only carry around 10kg max (22 freedom units).

Comment: It’s meant ironically (remember Freedom Fries?). I grew up with SI units myself.

Comment: P clips are the answer - your rack's stays bolt to the seat stays.   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5842/trying-to-fit-a-blackburn-ex1-rack-to-my-bike/5844

Comment: Do you already have your fat bike? Do you find it suitable for long term commuting?

Comment: Are you looking for a new fat bike with rack mounting eyelets, or for a rack to fit an existing one? Some companies also make bolt on eyelet where it is a clamp that secures around the seat stay etc that you can put where ever you need it and mount the rack to that.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the expedition/endurance race fat bikes will come with rack mounts.  If you plan on "packratting" and carrying groceries, you should avoid the seatpost only options.  They generally have low weight restrictions and can also have issues with the bags flopping into your wheels (they are often missing the side panels regular pannier racks have).

If you look around a bit more, it should be fairly easy to find fat bike companies making rigs that are rack ready.  At most of the winter endurance races, racks and sometimes panniers are common.  The Surly Pugsley (the original production fatbike) still comes with rack mounts (rear AND front).

Answer (score 1):

You can get a rack that mounts to the seat post and doesn’t require lower dropout holes. They’re designed for rear suspension bikes and other bikes that don’t have pannier mounting holes on the frame.

[image: searxh for seat stay rack]

The main problem with them is that seatpost mount racks are only for light duty with a max capacity of around 10kg (or 22 American freedom units). The other (minor) problem is that it makes it harder to raise and lower your seat.

As @criggie notes in comments, another option is P clips that use your wheel bolts to mount standard panniers. The only problem is the width of the rear wheel hub may make it hard to fit standard panniers.

You might also consider getting a trailer for doing your shopping.

Comment: "American freedom units", ha ha!

Answer (score -2):

This is one - Salsa
Built for adventure

[image: Blackborrow]

Comment: Down vote what is the problem?

Comment: Not my downvote but maybe they felt it looked too much like an ad. Naming the specific model of rack would be more helpful than quoting what looks like the manufacturer's slogan.